# facebook javascript api gives error on post like "(#3) Publishing likes through the API is only available for page access tokens"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to like a post using post id and access token.
Below is code for post like:

```
 FB.api("/"+feed.id+"/likes?access_token="+$rootScope.fbAccessToken, 'post',function(response) {
     console.log(response)
     if(response === true) {
         alert("done!");
     }
 });
```

I have checked my access token permissions with URL:https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

```
Below are access token permissions 
   "data": [
      {
         "permission": "user_about_me",
         "status": "granted"
      },
      {
         "permission": "email",
         "status": "granted"
      },
      {
         "permission": "manage_pages",
         "status": "granted"
      },
      {
         "permission": "publish_actions",
         "status": "granted"
      },
      {
         "permission": "public_profile",
         "status": "granted"
      }
   ]
}
```

It gives me javascript error:

> error: Object code: 3 fbtrace_id:"AWj/2RCyzbz" message:"(#3)
>   Publishing likes through the API is only available for page access
>   tokens" type:"OAuthException"

I am not getting how to like a post using javascript api. Please help in this issue.

Comment: why not just do exactly what the error message tells you and try with a page token instead? i assume you need publish_pages for that too.

Comment: @luschn I have used publish_pages as well, but still it gives same error.

Comment: so...did you use a page token?

Comment: No, you did not use a page token, because if you tried the API call `/me/permissions` with a page access token, you would have gotten an error message saying that there is no permissions edge on page objects.

Comment: Hi @CBroe 
I am stucked in same issue. 

Permission granted for "publish_pages" on my account but still I am getting this error. Can you suggest me what shall I can do to make "Like/Unlike an object" on facebook working via my app !!

Comment: @Upasna you simply can not like stuff in the name of a user any more via API. (And to do it in the name of a page makes little sense, unless your app is explicitly a page-managing app.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook restricted this feature's access. Users can no longer like posts. Now you can only do it if your token is a page type. More info in:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1754734484744033/